# Redirect to a view with contextual filters

Tags: views, 8, redirection

I would like to redirect the user to a view with some contextual filters on the submit of a custom form.

For now I use this :

```
$form_state->setRedirect('view.search.page_1', ['myvalue' => $value]);
```

But it add "myvalue" like this : `/search?myvalue=$value`

and what I want is : `/search/$value`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the route parameter names defined in the route.

You can check the route definition of this view display with help of the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) by visiting:

```
www.example.com/devel/routes
```

When you define contextual filters the route parameter names are usually `{arg_0}`, `{arg_1}` ...

So this could work:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('view.search.page_1', ['arg_0' => $value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not directly possible, you could however solve it with a small workaround:

```
$uri = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('base:/your-views-path/' . $value, ['absolute' => TRUE]);
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($uri);
```

Edit:
@4k4 has the better solution.