# Route to Url with contextual filters

Tags: 8, views, routes

I'm looking for a way to convert a route to an Url *with contextual filters added.* I can do it manually and it works, but I still think there should be a better, "Drupalish" way to do it.

- `Url::fromRoute('view.view_name.display_name'))` converts to the correct base route of the view. However, there doesn't seem to be a proper way to attach filter values to that Url.
- `Url::fromRoute('view.view_name.display_name', ['value' => $value])` would be nice but, in the case of views, this only adds query values. It would obviously work if the route was declared in `routing.yml` as a normal route with parameters (if the `value` passed in the array corresponds to a declared parameter, it will be replaced all right) but this isn't a manually declared route but one belonging to a view page.

As I said, string manipulation on the Url works, of course. But it just doesn't feel right.

Although the question is universal enough, if a use case is needed to see why this would be necessary, consider a view that shows the list of some entity and a corresponding archive block that summarizes the entities into links pointing to years or months. The block has to assemble links that point to the view the contextual filter added, eg:

- `/documents/listing/2020`
- `/documents/listing/202006`

where the view page itself resides at `/documents/listing`.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239342/redirect-to-a-view-with-contextual-filters

Comment: Silly me, I deserved it. I use `arg_N` all right in other places of the same project. Would you care to turn it into an answer so that I can duly accept it? :-)